# Angular reactive forms in an ionic modal component

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, ionic4

I cant seem to set the the `[FormGroup]="myForm"` in an ionic 4 modal page. The error i am getting it

```
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("
<ion-content padding>
<form [ERROR ->][formGroup]="myForm">
```

However this is not an error with importing the `ReactiveFormsModule` as is common with this error. The `ReactiveFormsModule` has been imported into the pages module file.

I have tested this on a normal page (ie not one that is used as a modal ) and there are no issues with creating the `<form [formGroup]="myForm">`

The error is only on the modal page.

Answer (score 3):

The issue was that the `ReactiveFormsModule` needed to be imported into the parent page of the modal page and not imported in the modal page itself.

Comment: Thanks this gave me a hint. My problem was I had imported ReactiveFormsModule already in the parent page's module but didn't add the modal component in the components section of parent page's module file.